# Ruby condition for inserting unique items into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that if you have an `array` and reference it as `array.uniq` it will return without any of the duplicates.

However in this case it is an array of objects (is that proper ruby speak?). I want each call to go into the `@calls` array unless the `call.from` is the same as a call_formatted object already present in the array.

How can I conditionally place these objects in the array if no other objects in the array have the same `call.from` value?

```
calls_raw.each do |call|       
        call_formatted = {
              :date => date,
              :time => time,
              :from => call.from,
              :duration => call.duration,
              :recording => recording,
        }
        @calls << call_formatted
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't it simplify things if you used a set? See http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Comment: @panmari, you don't mean a hash, with the keys being the values of `call.from`? If not, how would that work with a set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array.uniq { |item| item[:from] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `#map` to build your array for you and call `#uniq` on it...

```
calls_raw.map do |call|       
        {
              :date => date,
              :time => time,
              :from => call.from,
              :duration => call.duration,
              :recording => recording,
        }
end.uniq{|call| call[:from]}
```

The above approach will first build an array of calls larger than it may ultimately need to be, and the final call to #uniq will make the list unique.

Or, to avoid adding all the duplicates in the array, you could build it with a `Hash` as such:

```
calls_raw.each_with_object do |call, h|       
        h[call.from] ||= {
              :date => date,
              :time => time,
              :from => call.from,
              :duration => call.duration,
              :recording => recording,
        }
end.values
```

The `Hash` approach will use the first occurrence of call.from as it is being set with `||=`.  To use the last occurrence of call.from then use a straightforward assignment with `=`.

It's also been suggested to just use a `Set` instead of an `Array`.

To take that approach you're going to have to implement `#eql?` and `#hash` on the class we're populating the set with.

```
class CallRaw
  attr_accessor :from

  def initialize(from)
    self.from = from
  end

  def eql?(o)
    # Base equality on 'from'
    o.from == self.from
  end

  def hash 
    # Use the hash of 'from' for our hash
    self.from.hash
  end
end

require 'set'
s = Set.new
 => <Set: {}>

s << CallRaw.new("Chewbaca")
 => <Set: {<CallRaw:0x00000002211888 @from="Chewbaca">}> 

# We expect now, that adding another will not grow our set any larger
s << CallRaw.new("Chewbaca")
 => <Set: {<CallRaw:0x00000002211888 @from="Chewbaca">}> 

# Great, it's not getting any bigger
s << CallRaw.new("Chewbaca")
s << CallRaw.new("Chewbaca")
 => <Set: {#<CallRaw:0x00000002211888 @from="Chewbaca">}>
```

Awesome - the Set works!!!

Now, it is interesting to note that having implemented `#eql?` and `#hash`, we can now use `Array#uniq` without having to pass in a block.

```
a = Array.new

a << CallRaw.new("Chewbaca")
 => [<CallRaw:0x000000021e2128 @from="Chewbaca">] 

a << CallRaw.new("Chewbaca")
 => [<CallRaw:0x000000021e2128 @from="Chewbaca">, <CallRaw:0x000000021c2bc0 @from="Chewbaca">]

a.uniq
 => [<CallRaw:0x000000021e2128 @from="Chewbaca">]
```

Now, I'm just wondering if there is a badge that StackOverflow awards for having ***too much coffee*** before setting out to answer a question?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some reason it has to be an array, I'd store the data in a `Hash`, keyed by the `from` value.

Then it's easy and fast to look up an entry by the `from` value. You can choose to insert a new value only if there's no value already with the same key, or insert the new value and let it replace the old entry with that key.

Example:

```
calls = Hash.new

def add(call)
  if not calls[call.from]
    calls[call.from] = call
  end
end
```