# How to append a unique array of struct based on an attribute?

Tags: arrays, ruby, struct, append, unique

I have an array of structs and I need to keep them unique based on an attribute, `:num`. This array will be appended with new struct objects. If the new struct object has a duplicate `:num` attribute *value*, I want to remove the old element containing duplicate `:num` and replace it with the new one.

Here's what I mean. Let's set it up:

```
Gen = Struct.new(:num, :val)
arr = []
arr << Gen.new(11, "foo1")
arr << Gen.new(12, "foo2")

# [#<struct num=11, val="foo1">, #<struct num=12, val="foo2">]
```

Then I feed it with new structs. Let's construct them:

```
s1 = Gen.new(12, "foo10")
s2 = Gen.new(13, "foo3")
```

- If I do `arr << s1`, it will just append `s1` into `arr`.
- If I do `arr.uniq {|el| el.number}` after I did the above, it sometimes remove "foo10", but I want to always keep the latest struct.

When `s1` is appended into `arr`, it needs to replace the old `#<struct num=12, val="foo2">` struct because `s1` is the newest feed. Since `arr` already contains `:num`  12, we need to replace it with the new struct. Since `s2` contains a unique `:num`, it should be able to be appended no problem (even should `s2` contain a duplicate `:val`, it should not matter, I am only concerned with keeping `:num` unique).

In the end, I need `arr` to look like:

```
[#<struct num=11, val="foo1">, #<struct num=12, val="foo10">, #<struct num=13, val="foo3">]
```

The order of the array doesn't matter.

I've looked at [Add element to an array if it's not there already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004325/add-element-to-an-array-if-its-not-there-already), [Ruby condition for inserting unique items into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598296/ruby-condition-for-inserting-unique-items-into-an-array), [Remove duplicate elements from array in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365721/remove-duplicate-elements-from-array-in-ruby)
, and a few other posts. They are all mostly dealing with simple array, not array of structs.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Good catch! Edited :)

Comment: Is an `Array` a requirement here? You could implement your own collective class and use a core enum internally. Personally I'd recommend a `Hash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to maintain a hash whose keys are the values of `:num` and whose values are the associated struct. The hash (`h`) can be updated with a new struct (`st`) in the desired manner as follows.

```
def add_struct(h, st)
  h.update(st[:num]=>st)
end
```

Then when an array of current structs is required simply return the values of the hash.

See [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`). Recall that if hashes `h` and `g` both have a key `k`, the value of `k` in the hash `h.update(g)` (or `h.merge(g)`) equals `g[k]`. `h.update(st[:num]=>st)` is shorthand for `h.update({ st[:num]=>st })`. The return value of `add_struct` is the updated value of `h`.

Here's an example.

```
Gen = Struct.new(:num, :val)
```

```
s1 = Gen.new(11, "foo1")
  #=> #<struct Gen num=11, val="foo1">
s2 = Gen.new(12, "foo2")
  #=> #<struct Gen num=12, val="foo2">
s3 = Gen.new(12, "foo10")
  #=> #<struct Gen num=12, val="foo10">
s4 = Gen.new(13, "foo3")
  #=> #<struct Gen num=13, val="foo3">
```

```
h = {}
```

```
add_struct(h, s1)
  #=> {11=>#<struct Gen num=11, val="foo1">}
add_struct(h, s2)
  #=> {11=>#<struct Gen num=11, val="foo1">,
  #    12=>#<struct Gen num=12, val="foo2">}
add_struct(h, s3)
  #=> {11=>#<struct Gen num=11, val="foo1">,
  #    12=>#<struct Gen num=12, val="foo10">}
add_struct(h, s4) 
  #=> {11=>#<struct Gen num=11, val="foo1">,
  #    12=>#<struct Gen num=12, val="foo10">,
  #    13=>#<struct Gen num=13, val="foo3">}
```

```
h #=> {11=>#<struct Gen num=11, val="foo1">,
  #    12=>#<struct Gen num=12, val="foo10">,
  #    13=>#<struct Gen num=13, val="foo3">} 
h.values
  #=> [#<struct Gen num=11, val="foo1">,
  #    #<struct Gen num=12, val="foo10">,
  #    #<struct Gen num=13, val="foo3">]
```

Comment: I think there's a typo. Instead of `h.update(st=>st[:num])` I believe it should be `h.update(st[:number]=>st)`. Other than that, great solution. Thanks!

Comment: Iggy, thanks for the heads-up. I corrected that in testing but forgot to make the correction in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take the new `gen`s one by one. Find the corresponding old gen and let it have the new one's vualue. If no old gen is found, add the complete new gen.

```
Gen = Struct.new(:num, :val) 
arr = []
arr << Gen.new(11, "foo1")
arr << Gen.new(12, "foo2")

new_gens = [Gen.new(12, "foo10"),
            Gen.new(13, "foo3")]
#let's go
new_gens.each do |new_gen|
  match = arr.detect{|old_gen| old_gen.num == new_gen.num}
  match ? match.val = new_gen.val : arr << new_gen
end
  
p arr # =>[#<struct num=11, val="foo1">, #<struct num=12, val="foo10">, #<struct num=13, val="foo3">]
```

Comment: I didn't vote it as accepted answer bc in my use case I have a lot more attributes in my struct. The other answer is easier. However, I'm upvoting this because the sln technically works for the example I gave on my post. Thank you!